# Android populate Radio Button from a database table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, radio-button

I have followed this tutorial [this tutorial](http://mobileyogi.in/mobile-programming/populating-radio-buttons-in-android-with-database-data/) and setup my DatBas and the main activity to fit the tutorial.
And I am getting an error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.Tamar_appActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

The Tamar_appActivity code is:

```
        DatBas db = new DatBas(this);
    TamarDatabaseCursor c = db.getActress();

    if (c.moveToFirst())
        DisplayRadioButton(c);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No title found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();

}

public void DisplayRadioButton(Cursor c) {
    for (int i = 1; i < (c.getColumnCount()); i++) {
        RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup)      findViewById(R.id.NameSelectGroup);
        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
        rdbtn.setId(i);
        rdbtn.setText(c.getString(i));
        radiogroup.addView(rdbtn);
    }

}
```

And the DatBase Code is:

```
public class DatBas {


public static final String KEY_ROW_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE_PATH = "uri";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
public static final String KEY_BORN_DATE_YEAR = "age_year";
public static final String KEY_BORN_DATE_MONTH = "age_month";
public static final String KEY_BORN_DATE_DAY = "age_day";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TamatDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS = "settings";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 20;

private TamarDatabase thdb;
private static Context tcontext;
private SQLiteDatabase tdb;

private static class TamarDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TamarDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String ctSettings = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS
                + " ( " + KEY_ROW_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + KEY_IMAGE_PATH + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_NAME
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_BORN_DATE_YEAR + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_BABY_DATE_MONTH + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_BABY_DATE_DAY + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
        db.execSQL(ctSettings);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public DatBas(Context c) {
    tcontext = c;
}

public DatBas open() throws SQLiteException {
    thdb = new TamarDatabase(tcontext);
    tdb = thdb.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    thdb.close();
}

public long createEntrySettings(String bbdy, String bbdm, String bbdd,
        String pt, String bg, String bfName) {
    ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
    cv2.put(KEY_IMAGE_PATH, pt);
    cv2.put(KEY_NAME, bfName);
    cv2.put(KEY_GENDER, bg);
    cv2.put(KEY_BORN_DATE_YEAR, bbdy);
    cv2.put(KEY_BORN_DATE_MONTH, bbdm);
    cv2.put(KEY_BORN_DATE_DAY, bbdd);

    return tdb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, null, cv2);
}

public Cursor getDataSettings() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_IMAGE_PATH,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_GENDER, KEY_BORN_DATE_YEAR,
            KEY_BORN_DATE_MONTH, KEY_BORN_DATE_DAY };
    Cursor c = tdb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, columns, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    String results = "";

    int iRawId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROW_ID);
    int iBIPath = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_IMAGE_PATH);
    int iBName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iGender = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_GENDER);
    int iBBDateYear = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BORN_DATE_YEAR);
    int iBBDateMonth = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BORN_DATE_MONTH);
    int iBBDateDay = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BORN_DATE_DAY);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        results = results + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iRawId)
                + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iBIPath)
                + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iBName)
                + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iGender)
                + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iBBDateYear)
                + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iBBDateMonth)
                + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iBBDateDay) + "\n";
    }
    return c;
}

public String getDataSettingsBabyName() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_NAME};
    Cursor c = tdb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, columns, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    String results = "";

    int iRawId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROW_ID);
    int iBName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        String[] resultsS = new String[]{c.getString(iRawId), c.getString(iBName)       
        };
    }
    return results;
}




public static class TamarDatabaseCursor extends SQLiteCursor{

    /** The query for this cursor */
    private static final String QUERY = 
        "SELECT _id, uri, baby_name, gender, age_year, age_month, age_day" +
        " FROM settings";

    /** Cursor constructor */
    private TamarDatabaseCursor(SQLiteDatabase db, SQLiteCursorDriver driver,
            String editTable, SQLiteQuery query) {
        super(db, driver, editTable, query);
    }
    /** Private factory class necessary for rawQueryWithFactory() call */

    private static class Factory implements SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory{
        public Cursor newCursor(SQLiteDatabase db,
                SQLiteCursorDriver driver, String editTable,
                SQLiteQuery query) {
            return new TamarDatabaseCursor(db, driver, editTable, query);
        }
    }
    /* Accessor functions get one per database column */

    public int getActressId(){return getInt(getColumnIndexOrThrow("actress.actressId"));}

}



public TamarDatabaseCursor getActress()
{
SQLiteDatabase d = getReadableDatabase();
TamarDatabaseCursor c = (TamarDatabaseCursor)d.rawQueryWithFactory
        (new TamarDatabaseCursor.Factory(), TamarDatabaseCursor.QUERY, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
return c;
}



private SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public DatBas delete() {
    tdb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
    tdb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, null, null);
    return null;
}
}
```

The Main XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#3691c9"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/sideGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtnLeft"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="xxx" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtnRight"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="xxx" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/kindGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtnN"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="xxx" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtnP"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="xxx" />
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#363636"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#363636"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pause" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Resume" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stop" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/NameSelectGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/bNameSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="38dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.NameSelectGroup);

Comment: I looked at the tutorial and my opinion is it's a very bad tutorial. For example, the select statement:
`SELECT actressId,actress1,actress2,actress3,actress4 FROM actress;`

I would rather move on and find something else. At present Googling SQLite android and radio button frequently leads to this bad tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that `findViewById(R.id.babyNameSelectGroup);` is returning null, and when you try to `radiogroup.addView(rdbtn);` you get the NPE.

Have you done `setContentView(R.layout.yourmainlayout);` before you try to access a view contained in your layout?

**EDIT**

Your are looking for `babyNameSelectGroup`, which doesn't appear to exist in your layout (thus giving you the NPE).  Maybe it should be `NameSelectGroup`?

Comment: yes i did set the mainLayout:   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: OK.  How about posting the XML that contains `NameSelectGroup`?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "posting"?

Comment: Edit your question to put it in there so we can see it.  The error points to where you try to find that id, so it might help to see the xml file that contains it.  Another thing to look for, is there a line in the logcat that says something like "Caused by..."? If there is, the line number and what is at that line number could lead us closer to what is causing it.

Comment: After changed it, got this error: E/AndroidRuntime(421): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tamar.efrat/com.tamar.efrat.Tamar_appActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: The maximum line number is 324... I do not have line number 421. Where it should be locate?

Answer (score 0):

I had to set a `getReadableDatabase()` method:

```
    public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() throws SQLiteException {
    thdb = new TamarDatabase(tcontext);
    tdb = thdb.getReadableDatabase();
    return tdb;
}
```